# Ошибка zend_mm_heap corrupted

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего может возникать данная ошибка? Появляется у меня она при запуске скрипта из командной строки (`$php script.php`). OC win7 c  XAMPP version 1.7.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно код смотреть, может что-то в классе неправильно написано.

может memcashed переставить.

//upd

Гугл дал намек замены в php.ini

allow_call_time_pass_reference = On

на

allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off

Answer (score 0):

Дело оказало в переполнении памяти, я слишком много раз создавал один и тот же экземпляр класса, и это приводило к данной ошибке.